# checkin a one drive document using graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to checkout a drive item using microsoft graph API 
as mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_checkout#example

But when I am trying to use graph API explorer it gives me an error 
Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery: sites/bluejdemo.sharepoint.com/drives/...

[image: Details of error I am getting]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Screen shots are generally a poor way to show your problem (in this case it's entirely illegible for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check-in and check-out are only available in the /beta/ version of Microsoft Graph. I can see how the documentation doesn't make that clear, so sorry about that. I'll make sure we get those docs updated.

Here's call you need to make:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{insert your URL here}/checkout`